# ajax/jquery working in FF but not IE or Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with a sortable list. The list is populated dynamically based on the values from a database. My goal is to drag and drop the list items then reassign their new "order" to a field within my database. The code below works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. In those two browsers the drag and drop works so I suspect the problem is within my "re-sort function". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* sortable function */
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});

/* re-sort function */
function sort(){

    /* variables */
    var count = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByTagName('li').length;
    var flyerNum = document.getElementsByName('sortKey');
    var tempArray = new Array(); 
    var newOrder = new Array();
    var unorderedList = document.getElementById('sortable');
    var ListItems = unorderedList.getElementsByTagName('li');

    /* loop through list items */
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        flyerNum[i].setAttribute('value', i+1); /* increment list item */  
            tempArray[i] = i+1; /* increment array item */ 
            newOrder[i] = ListItems[i].value; /* re-assign array value */ 
    }

    document.getElementById('flyer_IDs').value = newOrder; /* re-assign array values */

    document.getElementById("editflyer").submit(); /* submit form */

};
```

Comment: Any error in chrome console?

Comment: your question title **ajax/jquery working in FF but not IE or Chrome** is way different than the actual question why?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but apparently `var tempArray = [];` is preferred over `var tempArray = new Array();`...something about performance, idk

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."